# Store the path of a subfolder with lowest size into a variable

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

Im coding something for bash, and I need to store the lowest size of a set of folders in a directory the data set will come from something like `du`.

For example

```
du -hd1 /path/to/dir/
    5GB /path/to/dir/1
    1GB /path/to/dir/2
    2GB /path/to/dir/3
    3GB /path/to/dir/4
    4GB /path/to/dir/5
```

In this case, how can I store the value of `/path/to/dir/2` into a variable like `$smallest`?

Comment: Something like: `var=$(sort -k1h folderlistfie.txt | head -n1 | cut -d ' ' -f2-); echo "$var"`

Comment: I should have mentioned that the command was from `du`

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
smallest="$(du -d1 /some/folder|sort -n|head -1|awk {'print $2'})"
echo $smallest
```

Comment: If you are using awk, then awk it entirely :)

Answer (score 1):

No `awk` needed

```
du -d1 /path/to/dir | sort -n | head -1 | cut -f 2
```

Comment: Right! although it spawns 3 sub-shell forks and 3 commands (one for each pipe

Comment: yes, I was optimizing the amount of chars to be typed... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use:

> smallest=$(du -d1 /path/to/dir/ | sort -nr | tail -1 | awk '{print$2}')
>
> echo $smallest

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` only to parse `du` output:

```sh
smallest=$(du -d1 | awk 'NR==1||$1<n{n=$1;d=$2}END{print d}')
```

The awk script itself:

```
NR == 1 || $1 < size {
  size=$1
  dir=$2
}
END {
  print dir
}
```